Python Not Recognized in Scripts Executed via Cron
Summary
I'm obtaining an error when running a bash script via cron. The script errors out when it reaches the following command; keep in mind that the bash script swaps out ${END_DATE} with the date the script was run:
python -c "import shutil; shutil.make_archive('packages/weekly-report-${END_DATE}', 'zip', 'output/${END_DATE}/')"

Error produced (line 53 is what I posted above):
line 53: python: command not found

Cron settings (python snippet is located in the bash script):
m h dom mon dow   command
5 3 * * 1 /data/run-WP046-cronjob.sh

Shebang for bash script: #!/bin/bash
What I've Tried
I do not get this error when running the script as my profile.  Python successfully imports shutil & zips my desired directory. Has anyone experienced this? I've looked online and can't find similar problem examples.
Please let me know if I'm missing needed information for this question.

The diagnostic presented says that it is the python command that is not found.  That doesn't appear to have anything to do with shutil.  Consider specifying the full path to the python executable you want to run, maybe /usr/bin/python.

John, I just recognized while you were posting it was saying it didn't recognize the python command, not the shutil function. Updating title.

John, are you recommending I replace the script line to something similar to: /usr/bin/python -c "import shutil; shutil.make_archive('packages/weekly-report-${END_DATE}', 'zip', 'output/${END_DATE}/')"

Yes, I am recommending that.  Alternatively, if you have other commands that you expect to be able to resolve via the $PATH, then you could consider setting an appropriate PATH.  It is not safe to rely on cron to provide the same one that you get by default in an interactive shell.

Make sure the executable isn't called "python3", too.

If you can run your script in your normal shell by typing python -c ... then run type python and it will tell you the full path to use in cron. If you use python3 -c ... in your normal shell, run type python3 to get the full path.

Thanks Mark & Ulrich. I did verify everything was running python, not python3. Also this was the only command to rely on $PATH John.

As John Bollinger pointed out the full path to the executable needed to be specified. I update the script to point to it and error has been corrected. Thank you comment section! Script update below:
/usr/bin/python -c "import shutil; shutil.make_archive('packages/weekly-report-${END_DATE}', 'zip', 'output/${END_DATE}/')"

It does not need to be specified. If you set the variable PATH so that it contains usr/bin, you can use simply python.

How would I set PATH in this case?

??? Well, obviously in a way that it contains /usr/bin. In the simplest case, this would be export PATH=/usr/bin, but of course if you need other directories too, you need to include them as well. In any case, make yourself familiar with the PATH variable. It's such a basic concept in Unix-like operating systems, that you will always get into trouble if you don't understand it.

Read into this more over holiday. That makes sense and I'll work on modifying the bash script to implement this solution.
Question: If this was a purely python script I could specify the PATH in the shebang definition, correct?

No. The #!  can only contain the abspath of the program, and one additional word which will be passed to that program. In a pure Python program, you would set the PATH for those commands which get executed as child processes of your Python program, in your Python code explicitly (using os.environ).
